# Target Unreachable, returned null

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

i'm experiencing problems while trying to use the object currentActeurObjetProjet and display its attributes on a dialog using Primefaces but it keeps showing this error:

> ATTENTION: /infoprojet.xhtml @493,159 value="#{acteurObjetProjetBean.currentActeurObjetProjet.objets.nomObjet}": Target Unreachable, 'objets' returned null
>   javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /infoprojet.xhtml @493,159 value="#{acteurObjetProjetBean.currentActeurObjetProjet.objets.nomObjet}": Target Unreachable, 'objets' returned null

here is the back up bean:

```
package com.mycompany.projet;
.......

/**
 *
 * @author Omar
 */
@Component("etatsBean")
@Scope("session")
public class ActeurObjetProjetBean implements Serializable{
   .......
    private ActeurObjetProjet currentActeurObjetProjet=new ActeurObjetProjet();
   .......
     ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Méthodes & fonctions\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// setters & getters \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ 
    public void setCurrentActeurObjetProjet(ActeurObjetProjet currentActeurObjetProjet)
    {
        this.currentActeurObjetProjet=currentActeurObjetProjet;
    }
    public ActeurObjetProjet getCurrentActeurObjetProjet()
    {
        return currentActeurObjetProjet;
    } 
    .......
}
```

here is my page code:

```
<p:dialog header="Editer Objet" widgetVar="editobjetDialog" resizable="true" width="300" height="300" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip" modal="true">
                                    <p:outputPanel id="editobjetDetail" style="text-align:center;" layout="block">
                                        <center>
                                            <h:panelGrid  columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                                                 <h:outputLabel  value="Nom Objet        "/>
                                                 <p:inputText value="#{acteurObjetProjetBean.currentActeurObjetProjet.objets.nomObjet}" style="width: 180px"/>
                                                                                                         <h:outputLabel  value="Accès DB2        "/>
                                                 <p:inputText value="#{acteurObjetProjetBean.currentActeurObjetProjet.objets.accesDb2}" style="width: 180px"/>
                                                 <h:outputLabel  value="Etat        "/>
                                                 <p:inputText value="#{acteurObjetProjetBean.currentActeurObjetProjet.objets.etatObjet}" style="width: 180px"/>
                                                 <h:outputLabel  value="Version        "/>
                                                 <p:inputText value="#{acteurObjetProjetBean.currentActeurObjetProjet.objets.versionObjet}" style="width: 180px"/>

                                            </h:panelGrid>
                                        </center>
                                    </p:outputPanel>
                                </p:dialog>
```

Regards

Comment: It could either be that you are missing some getter/setter or your object (property) is not properly initialized. Are you sure that `objets` is properly initialized and has getter/setter in `ActeurObjetProjet`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /infoprojet.xhtml @493,159 value="#{acteurObjetProjetBean.currentActeurObjetProjet.objets.nomObjet}": Target Unreachable, 'objets' returned null

EL is trying to tell you that it cannot set the `nomObjet` value because `objets` is `null`. EL won't autocreate any nested object properties for you. It will only autofill the leaf property. You just have to make sure that the `objet` property of the `currentActeurObjetProject` class is not `null`. You can do that by preparing it in for example the constructor of the `ActeurObjetProjet` class.

```
public ActeurObjetProjet() {
    this.objet = new Objet();
}
```

You can also do that in the constructor of `ActeurObjetProjetBean` instead.

```
private ActeurObjetProjet currentActeurObjetProject;

public ActeurObjetProjetBean() {
    this.currentActeurObjetProject = new ActeurObjetProjet();
    this.currentActeurObjetProject.setObject(new Object());
}
```

Choose whatever suits the functional/business requirements the best.